# How to add transparency values correctly?

Tags: html5-canvas, alpha

The following example draws two boxes. The first box is just one box drawn with a `globalAlpha` of 1. The second box is the sum of 2 boxes with `globalAlpha` of 0.5.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";

ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;

ctx.fillRect(100, 0, 100, 100);
ctx.fillRect(100, 0, 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

It seems to me that the two alpha values of 0.5 do not sum to 1, because the boxes do not have the same color. This is how it looks on my screen.

[image: boxes]

How to bisect an alpha correctly?

Comment: They don't sum, they overlay (just as multiple transparent things on top of each other in real life do not block 100% of the light through them). But what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to split a blue box into two boxes such that when the two boxes are drawn over each other give exactly the original box.

Comment: You pretty much can't, unless one of them *is* the original box, since any two not-fully-opaque things together do not form a fully-opaque thing together (apart from rounding maybe). Two things of 50% together make 75%, two things of 80% make 96% and so on.

Comment: If I use [0.73](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/152379/20770) the result is almost perfect. But I am not sure if Gimp and the HTML canvas do work in the same way.

Comment: They don't, that gamma stuff is a red herring. When you overlay something with alpha X over something with alpha Y, the result has an alpha of `X + Y * (1 - X)`.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to work somehow, but I am not sure if I can rely on 2.2.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

ctx.fillStyle = "#00f";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

const gamma = 2.2;
const count = 100;

ctx.globalAlpha = Math.pow(1/count, 1/gamma);

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)
  ctx.fillRect(100, 0, 100, 100);
```

```css
canvas {
  background: repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0deg 25%, #fff 0deg 50%) 0 / 2em 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

The error is visible for 100 iterations.

```js
const gamma = 2.2;
const iterations = document.getElementById("iterations");
const color = document.getElementById("color");
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
const hover = [0, 1, 2, 3].map(id => document.getElementById(id));

function draw() {
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = color.value;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  const count = Number(iterations.value);
  ctx.globalAlpha = Math.pow(1/count, 1/gamma);
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)
    ctx.fillRect(100, 0, 100, 100);
}  
draw();

iterations.addEventListener("change", ev => draw());
color.addEventListener("change", ev => draw());
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", ev => {
  const pixel = ctx.getImageData(ev.clientX - rect.left, ev.clientY - rect.top, 1, 1);
  pixel.data.forEach((v, i) => {hover[i].value = v;});
});
```

```css
canvas {
  background: repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0deg 25%, #fff 0deg 50%) 0 / 2em 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Iterations: <input type="number" id="iterations" value="1000"/></p>
<p>Color: <input type="color" id="color" value="#ffffff"/></p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
<div>R: <output id="0"></output></div>
<div>G: <output id="1"></output></div>
<div>B: <output id="2"></output></div>
<div>A: <output id="3"></output></div>
```

Comment: The results will also change based on the input color. If one of the channels is zero you won't be able to reach the same color. And it's assuming a white background, the actual pixels aren't opaque and only match when over white.

Comment: The result for "blue" is even better than for "salmon".

Comment: Not on my setup. I get #0404FF instead of #0000FF over the white background. But the actual color on the canvas is anyway far off since the alpha channel is not opaque.

Comment: But is it a failure of the solution or is it just the error your get when you increment a floating point number 100 times? I think an error of 1.5% may be acceptable for 100 iterations. It is quite difficult to notice it.

Comment: It's a failure to understand how alpha blending works? What you're after isn't possible, that's just not how it works. And yes it may be very visible, just set your body's `background` to `repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0deg 25%, #fff 0deg 50%) 0 / 2em 2em` and you will see that your rectangle isn't opaque.